# How to call a textbox that is in GridView

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView and in one of those columns is a textbox. When this textbox is selected it pops up a list of pieces. When a piece is selected I need to show the piece in the textbox.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpPieceDetails" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView  style="width:75%;float:left"  
                        ID="gvPieceOutturns" 
                        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false"
                        CssClass="tblResults" 
                        runat="server" 
                        OnRowDataBound="gvPieceOutturns_ItemDataBound"                             
                        DataKeyField="ID" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        allowpaging="false"
                        AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EEEEEE">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
                        <Columns>  
                           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Outturn Pce" SortExpression="OutturnPce">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <a style="float:none;width:16px;height:16px;margin-right:0px;left:0px;top:26px" title="Pick Type from list..." class="iconSearch" id="btnMemShowPieceType"></a>  
                                    <input type="text" id="txtMemPieceType" class="lookuppopup" onblur="CheckMemPiece(this.value)"   style="text-transform:uppercase;width:40px" runat="server"/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>     
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here I am trying to populate the textbox:

```
function PopulateMemPiece(result) {
        if (result.ID > 0) {
            $("#<%= hfPieceType.ClientID %>").val(result.ID);
            $("#<%= txtMemPieceType.ClientID %>").val(result.Code);

        } else {
            $("#<%= hfPieceType.ClientID %>").val(0);
            $("#<%= txtMemPieceType.ClientID %>").val("");
        }
    }
```

But I get this error:

> Error 2586    The name 'txtMemPieceType' does not exist in the current
>   context

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't

```
gvPieceOutturns.FindControl("hfPieceType");
```

work ?

You can also try

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

on your TextBoxes, to use jQuery on them.

Comment: If I use the` FindControl` how do I populate the textbox when a piece is selected?

Comment: Set it, and update then UpdatePanel, have the tb as AsyncPostBackTrigger. ALso you might need to set AutoPostBack to the TextBox as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since your trying to access that control in JavaScript but it is nested inside an Gridview I would suggest that you create a Property in the code-behind that resolves that control.  I would add the following property to the .cs file:

Edit: The control is also nested inside a TemplateField, so we will need to iterate through the rows of the Gridview to find the desired row which needs to be updated.

```
protected HtmlInputText txtMemPieceType
{
    get { return findMemPieceType(); }
}

private HtmlInputText findMemPieceType()
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvPieceOutturns.Rows)
    {
        if (/* Determine which row has the info you need */)
        {
            return row.FindControl("txtMemPieceType") as HtmlInputText;
        }
    }       
}
```

You will need to come up with a way to distinguish which row needs to be updated.  Alternativly if the row in question can trigger a Gridview Event like [RowCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) when the item is selected, then you can do something similar to this:

```
protected HtmlInputText txtMemPieceType { get; set; }

void gvPieceOutturns_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridViewRow row = ContactsGridView.Rows[index];
    txtMemPieceType = row.FindControl("txtMemPieceType") as HtmlInputText;
}
```

Comment: I get the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object with `$("#<%= txtMemPieceType.ClientID %>").val(result.Code); `

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that you where using `HtmlInputText` and not `Texbox`.  I edited my answer, see if that works.

Comment: I edited my answer again, since the control is inside a TemplateField it looks like it will be more involved.